# How can I pass data to a separate component which is loaded by a redirect?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to let users of my website see their basic information on a `Dashboard` component after they log in.

So far I've figured out that I have to assign the result of the `axios` log in request to a variable and then pass it. The question is: How can I pass that? From what I know, I can only pass data down from parent to child and the `Dashboard` is a completely separate component which gets loaded by calling `props.history.push`.

So far my request looks like:

```
const handleSubmitLogin = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const isValid = validateLogin();
    if (isValid) {
      axios
        .post(baseUrl + "User/SignIn", {
          username: formDetails.loginUsername,
          password: formDetails.loginPassword,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          localStorage.setItem("cool-jwt", res.data.result.tokenString);
          res = res.data.result;
          props.history.push("/dashboard");
          console.log(res);
        return res;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });

      setFormDetails(INIT_STATE);
    }
};
```

After a successful login, the user gets redirected to his dashboard where I want to access the `res` data and let him see his customerID, username and email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`props.history.push`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#history.push) accepts a second argument `state`.  You can use this argument to pass the data which you want to be able to access from the `Dashboard` component.

```
.then((res) => {
    localStorage.setItem("cool-jwt", res.data.result.tokenString);
    const result = res.data.result;
    props.history.push("/dashboard", {
        customerId: result.id,
        username: result.username, 
        email: result.email,
    });
```

Inside the `Dashboard` component, access the `state` through the `location` via  `props.location.state` or the `useLocation` hook.

```
const {state} = useLocation();
```

Comment: Sadly I dont use functional component so I can't use that great hook but I did handle it with props.location.state !! THANK YOU <3 !

Comment: You taught me a lot

Comment: When in doubt, check the docs :)  You'll find things that you didn't you you could do.